# Why does the terminal throws Gin-debug Error in Go lang application?

Tags: visual-studio, go, error-handling, exitstatus

I was trying to run my go application but have come across this error , thrown to me as [GIN-debug] [ERROR] listen tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

I have tried running these commands "net stop hns && net start hns" in windows shell as @admin but still cannot overcome this error.

How to resolve this?